# Fill reactive forms with one Observable

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

Please I need help with my question, this is Which is the best approach by fill one reactive forms with **patchValue** but with one Observable. In this case my two approach is:

**1)**

```
ngOnChanges() {
  this.data.subscribe(result => this.form.patchValue(result));
}
```

**2**

```
ngOnChanges() {
  this.data.pipe(
   tap(result => this.form.patchValue(result))
  );
}
```

The problem is that both have the following error:

[image]

Thanks for your responses

Comment: Feel you haven't defined `form`. Try `form:FormGroup;`. And be careful `ngOnChanges` life cycle hook works before `ngOnInit`

Comment: yes, in my declarations I have definied my form group with .    form: FormGroup;

Comment: Can you update how you define the form?

Comment: Varman the form will be created in `OnInit`, later I edit the form and fill it with `patchValue` in `OnChanges`, is the approach correct?

Comment: Thats totally fine, but how you edit it? update the code, otherwise its difficult to find

Comment: I found the solution, I Put the result of the `data` against an `observable var` and at the top of the form place this variable `<form * ngIf = "var | async;`   as in this example:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uquzq9 .   Thanks very much for your time varman